# ASP.NET Web Forms Microsoft OAuth2 redirect_uri issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, oauth-2.0, .net-4.5

I have created a new **WebForms** application using the standard template provided in VS2013. I need to integrate Microsoft authentication into it. After going through many tutorials/blogs I have finally..

1. Hosted my webapp on Azure.
2. Registered my application on
   *account.live.com/developers/* and obtained the **Client ID** and **Secret**. On that portal I have set the **redirect_uri** to `http://myxyzapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-microsoft`
3. I have Updated AuthConfig.cs as..

   ```
   public static void RegisterOpenAuth()
   {  
   OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddMicrosoft(  
   clientId: "----MyClientID----",clientSecret: "----MyClientSecret----"); 
   }
   ```

However when I run the app and enter my Microsoft credentials to login I get the error message : **Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.**
The response header says: `The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches the redirect URI registered for this client application.`

Can somesone please guide me where should I specify this **redirect_uri** ? I have gone through many similar questions on SO and other forums but didn't get any specific answer involving WebForms and Microsoft OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

log in with your microsoft account and go here
https://account.live.com/developers/applications/
select your application (or create a new one)
then press "Edit settings" and "API settings"
you will then find the "Redirect URLs: "field on the right side pane

Comment: I already have the redirect_uri. I want to know where should I use this in ASP.NET code?

Comment: in the Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll assembly there is the MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationExtensions which defines two extension method for the IAppBuilder interface one of the two  allows you to pass a MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions which has the CallbackPath property. i suppose that there you can define the callback address in case you don't want to use the default one. anyway the default one is already /signin-microsoft

Comment: anyway, if you are testing it in a development environment you should configure your local web server to respond at the domain registered in the redirect_uri property and also change the host file so to loopback locally. unfortunately localhost is not a valid redirect uri for the microsoft service :( too bad